# Making subplots with whole dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I work with data set which is available on this link https://www.kaggle.com/thomaskonstantin/bank-churn-data-exploration-and-churn-prediction.
My intention is to make plots for each numerical data. In order to do that I already make code which iterate through columns and make bar plots. You can see code and output from this code below

```
dataset_num = dataset.select_dtypes(include = ['float64', 'int64'])
dataset_num.head()
dataset_num.hist(figsize=(16, 20), bins=50, xlabelsize=8, ylabelsize=8);
```

[image]

Now  I want to make boxplots and also pie chart for each variable on similar way like code above.I try with on this way but obviously I made some mistake.

```
dataset_num.plot(figsize=(16, 20), kind='box', xlabelsize=8, ylabelsize=8);
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this and make boxplots and pie charts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for boxplots:

```
dataset_num.plot(figsize=(16, 20), kind='box', subplots=True, layout=(4, 5))
```

[image: boxes]

For pie plots, you will need at least one categorical variable.